# Asp.net MVC + NoSQL Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nosql, cassandra

Is there any good/simple asp.net MVC application that uses NoSQL database(cassandra). Any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a specific example, but perhaps using a linq provider like [Cassandraemon](http://cassandraemon.codeplex.com/)  will help align the many existing ASP.NET MVC examples with using a Cassandra database.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer, but I came across it and thought it would be useful.

[Chirper](http://www.sinbadsoft.com/blog/chirper-twitter-clone-webapp-with-net-front-end-and-cassandra-nosql-back-end/)